# iOS:View controller crashes when trying to use camera in an application.

Tags: objective-c, ios, navigation

I have a button where when the user presses it, he is navigated to camera to take a pic.

When he takes the pic, he presses done and gets back to the controller. But when that happens the navigation bar gets up in the screen, gets below the battery/signal bar that the telephone has. The weird thing is that **this happens on 4/4s but not on 3gs**

Comment: can u post some code please.....

Comment: no because its an enormous project.. i am just asking in general what could have gone wrong to see such a weird behaviour

Comment: i never said i need ur PROJECT. i said your code it will be easier for us to see what u have done rather then speculate. Anyways take a look at this code From Apple Reference [Link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoPicker/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html)

Comment: Without seeing any code it is rather tough, one of my guesses would be that something isn't being closed/released properly.  Are you using ARC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is rather tough to answer the question without knowing a bit more details, but here's some code I use to bring up the camera, take the picture, then close the camera successfully.  The method can be called by using one line of code: `[self takePhoto];`

```
- (void) takePhoto {

    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
        //Clear out the UI first

        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

        picker.delegate = self;

        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        //picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary; -> use this if you want them to select from the library
        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
    } else {
        //Device does not support a camera, show a message if desired
    }

}
```

Then you need a delegate for it all so the program knows what to do when an image is taken or selected and how to close, that's what this code is:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    self.workingImage = nil;

    //I grab the image and store globally, but first I manually scale and rotate it if necessary    
    self.workingImage = [self scaleAndRotateImage:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]];

    //I display the image in my UI view, so this chunk of code will size it properly
    CGRect bound;
    bound.origin = CGPointZero;
    bound.size = img.size;
    imageView.bounds = bound;

    //Set the UI image view and dismiss the controller
    [imageView setImage:self.workingImage];
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

Obviously, make sure your controller .h implements the delegate properly like so:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate> { ... }
```

Hope this helps?